# ckgedit paste from word not working

Tags: ckeditor

I installed the plugin ckgedit that use ckeditor

I have problems with the option "Paste from Word".

In fact, when I copy a text with colorful characters, the text is pasted correctly in the popup "Paste from Word". 
But when I press OK the text is inserted but lost formatting.

[see attached sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqs2S.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show how you configured the editor and the plugin.